# Probability of two partners having 3 spades each (Bridge game)

Tags: combinatorics, card-games

**Problem.** A bridge player and his partner are known to have six spades between them. Find the
the probability that the spades will be split 3-3.

**Solution.**

In the 26-26 distribution of cards between the two pairs of partners we want that in one pair the partners receive 3 spades each and the second receives the remaining spades at any pattern. Thus we only have to deal with the distribution of the 6 spades within the first pair.

In particular, it suffices to fill the hand of one of the partners, since the other is automatically determined. For one of the partners, choose 3 spades out of 6 in ${6\choose 3}$ ways, then choose 10 cards from the remaining 20. So there are
$$
{6\choose 3}{20\choose10}
$$
overall ways to distribute the 6 spades among the partners s.t. they both have 3 spades.

Furthermore, there are ${26 \choose 13}$ overall ways to draw 26 cards for two partners, so the probability is
$$
\frac{{6\choose 3}{20\choose10}}{{26 \choose 13}}.\quad(*)
$$

Now the question is: if the pair is **not fixed** beforehand, is the answer equal to $2!$ times $(*)$?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  "*if the pair is not fixed beforehand*"  If what pair is not fixed beforehand?  The pair of partners?  What other way of fixing the pair is possible?  Are you suggesting that rather than North/South being our partners it was instead East/West?  How does that matter?  We were told that whichever partner pair it was we were talking about, they had six spades.  Only one partner pair at a time can have six spades.  Partner pairs in bridge are always sitting across the table from one another.

Comment: Are you perhaps worried about whether it was North in North/South or if it was South in North/South what we chose for filling the hand with?  Technically, you should have in the step "*it suffices to fill the hand of one of the partners*" specified something along the lines of "Pick whichever of the partners occurs first clockwise around the table starting from north" or "Pick whichever of the partners has the highest age" or some other way of unambiguously selecting which it is.  Your answer at (*) is correct.  Had you not done this, then sure... you could multiply BOTH top and bottom by 2!

Comment: There is no interpretation of the problem I can see where the answer should have been twice what you wrote in (*).

Comment: Yes, I am confused about the fact that I see the partners as ordered pairs (North/South,West/East) and (*) is the probability of the distribution of the 13 spades in say (6,7). But there is also the distribution (7,6)...

Comment: "*A bridge player and his partner are known to have six spades.*"  Now... the problem didn't tell us which seat our bridge player in the question or his partner are sitting in.  We *could* if we *really wanted to* do the problem four times... one for each of the different ways in which they are sitting.  Once for if our bridge player was sitting in the north seat and his partner in the south... do it again for if our player was in east and his partner in west... but why on earth would we subject ourselves to such torture?

Comment: We can say [without loss of generality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality) suppose our player was sitting in the north seat and his partner in south... since regardless where we actually said they were sitting the answer would come out to be the same.

Comment: "...the problem didn't tell us which seat our bridge player in the question or his partner are sitting in..." this was my doubt. Do I have to take into account all the possible positions of the partners (e.g. 2, if we think that realistically they sit in front of each other) or just work it out with any position ? But you clarified my doubt. Thank you!